# Ubuntu 20.04 LTS apt update error => E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead

Tags: apt, updates, error-handling

I'm receiving this error message when trying to update the apt repository in a Ubuntu 20.04 LTS. First time this happens, generally it works fine.

I tried to look for answers, but did not found someone with the same problem in this version of Ubuntu, only in older ones.

I tried erasing the cache already, but the error persisted.

```
sudo apt update
```

The error message is as such:

```
E: Failed to fetch
http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz
File has unexpected size (279160 != 279228). Mirror sync in progress?
[IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]    Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:279228 [weak]
    - SHA256:78f28646eccfe2b6f38ad2186e2888630ad7603dc6ca7f900edb301d3f0a7e75
    - SHA1:8e9d240ba7b8e641a505f39219ac03af43152af6 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:42fdba3fddf8ed8719269cd7489af40b [weak]    Release file created at: Wed, 19 Jan 2022 14:21:17 +0000 

E: Failed to fetch
http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz

E: Failed to fetch 
http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/multiverse/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz

E: Failed to fetch
http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/main/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz

File has unexpected size (7992 != 7984). Mirror sync in progress? [IP: 2801:82:80ff:8000::5 80]    Hashes of expected file:
    - Filesize:7984 [weak]
    - SHA256:9cacb7791c51451db28fade0b4affa3425b33ce5c0a5a9604d46bbe1b77962f4
    - SHA1:be70071da1e1ccd98b0eebcdaae7ce83ebf26aa6 [weak]
    - MD5Sum:901f543f4f5e8065adb8f7101dcc0529 [weak]    Release file created at: Wed, 19 Jan 2022 14:22:09 +0000 

E: Failed to fetch
http://br.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/universe/dep11/Components-amd64.yml.xz
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

First time using this forum... I'm grateful for the attention, folks. Recently started the Linux universe, seems to have a great community.

Comment: If the messages are accurate, you may have been updating at the same time as the repositories were being refreshed. Updating again may resolve the issue. If you run into this regularly, perhaps a different set of servers would be better. I generally use the `uk.archive` servers as they're faster than my local ones (despite the half-planet distance) 

Comment: Thank you for the tip. I believe it was indeed the case, as I| tried again later and it worked just fine. Salutes from Brazil!